# iOS linker error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_EVP_sha1"

Tags: ios, security, linker

I get a whole bunch of linker errors which seem to be related to security framework (which I have included already).  What other framework do I need to include to find these symbols:

[image]

Comment: Please try to add libssl and libcrypto in your project.and hopfuly your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was that I was trying to run the code on the simulator.  The errors went away when I ran it on the actual device.